# Add a Character Between Strings in C++

Tags: c++, string

So basically I'm trying to add a character in the middle of a string. Normally in something like Python, this would be pretty straightforward, but I'm really not sure how to achieve this in C++. What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
void converter(){
    converted = ":regional_indicator_" + character + ":";

}
```

So basically, I'm trying to add the variable `character` of a type char in a string. Should I be storing character as a string instead?

For reference here's all of my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string inputLine;
char character;
string converted;

void input(){
    cout << "Please input the text in which you would like to be converted" << endl;
    cin >> inputLine;
}


void converter(){
    converted = ":regional_indicator_" + character + ":";

}
int main(){
    input();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputLine.length(); i++ ){
        character = tolower(inputLine[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
converted = ":regional_indicator_" + std::string(1, character) + ":";
```

This works because adding a string literal (`const char *`) to a string yields a string. But adding `const char *` and char results in pointer arithmetic. So, by constructing a `std::string` from "character" you end up with `const char *` + `std::string` yielding a string and then `std::string` + `const char *` again yields a string as the final result.

Comment: You should probably explain *why* this particular variant works.

Comment: pretty sure `":regional_indicator_"` should use a string literal, also `const char*` is not a [`std::string` literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)

Comment: I just ended up storing the character variable as a string, is there any upside to converting the character to a string rather than simply storing as a string from the start or vice-versa?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @jacksons123 Not much, but it might be slightly slower an incur an additional heap memory allocation if the compiler does not realize that the string is a global that is never modified.

Answer (score 3):

Append `s` behind the strings literals to treat them as `std::string`s instead of `const char*`s:

```
converted = ":regional_indicator_"s + character + ":"s;
```

You would need to do either `using namespace std::literals` or `using namespace std::string_literals` for it to work.

On a side note, in C++, it is strange to have a function `converter()` to modify a global variable using another global variable.  You might want to consider passing `character` as a parameter to the function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid invoking the std::string() constructor and memory allocation by using following. I have tested this before posting and it works:

```
void converter(){
    converted = ":regional_indicator_";
    converted.push_back(character);
    converted.push_back(':');
}
```

It's better because "converted" already will have some extra memory reserved, so you will just be filling that extra memory with two more characters and won't be allocating new memory.

Answer (score 0):

The wasy way to build strings is to use a [std::ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) like this:

```
void converter(){

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << ":regional_indicator_" << character << ":";

    converted = oss.str(); // copy the string out

    // ... etc ...
}
```

The added advantage of that method is it converts numbers to string automatically too.

That's not the fastest way so if speed was important I would take advantage of the static nature of this concatenation like this:

```
std::string converter(){

    static char* template = ":regional_indicator_X:";
    template[20] = character; // replace the `X` with your character
    converted.assign(template, 21); // assign your string all at once

    // ... etc ...
}
```

That works because your string is of fixed length. If thread safety is required you can use `thread_local static char* template...`.