# Why do i can't add an string to an letter of another string?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdstring

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main(){
    std::string word = "This is string";
    std::string word1 = "a" + word[0];
    std::cout << word1;
}
```

As you can see, i heve a string with the name `word` and i want to add first letter of it to another string and store them to string `word1`. when i run code, I expect that output is `aT`, but the output is  `╨≥ ╨≥ ╨≥ ╨≥ P≥ ►≥ @≥ ╕♠≥` ! What does this mean? How do i fix it? (Also note that my IDE is Code::Blocks 20.03)

Comment: [Dupe that explains the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705956/c-adding-string-literal-to-char-literal) and [Dupe that gives the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369760/add-a-character-between-strings-in-c)

Comment: *"i heve a string with the name `word` and i want to add first letter of it to another string and store them to string `word1`."* -- more precisely: you have a `std::string` with the name `word` and you want to add the first letter of it to a **string literal** and store them to `std::string` `word1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"a"` is not a string (well, its a c-string, but not a `std::string`, and a c-string is just an array). Its a `const char[2]` and decays to a pointer when `+` is applied. There is an `operator+` for `std::string` though:

```
std::string word1 = std::string("a") + word[0];
```

or

```
std::string word1 = "a"s + word[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, But even if i change "a" to "ab", i get that error again Although "ab" is not char.

Comment: @Amin `"ab"` is a c-cstring, a `const char [3]`, just like `"a"` is a `const char [2]`. A `char` literal is `'a'`, but adding `char` wont works as well. Adding two `char`s adds their numerical value, it does not concatenate them to a string

Comment: @Amin note the `"a"s` in the answer, which makes it a `std::string`.